# Setting default DeleteBehavior for every One-to-Many Relationship in EF Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

I am setting up some custom standards for my Entity Framework Project (EF Core 6).
One thing I want to avoid is using the Fluent API for each and every relationship.

I want One-to-Many relationships to have a default DeleteBehavior of DeleteBehavior.Restrict. If it is an optional relationship it should be DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull.

Here is an example of how I want to handle One-to-Many Relationships.
I have three Entities: Project, User and Client with the following relationship:
[image: Simple ER Model]

In detail that means:
*One Project has exactly one client.*
*One Client can be associated with 0 or many Projects.*

*One Project has exactly one Owner (User).*
*One User can be associated with 0 or Many Projects.*

For the DeleteBehavior I am expecting:
A Client cannot be deleted if he is associated with a Project.
A User cannot be deleted if he is associated with a Project.

Now, my classes look like this:

**Project.cs**

```
[Table(nameof(Project))]
public class Project
{
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Owner))]
    public long OwnerId { get; set; }
    public virtual User Owner { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Client))]
    public long ClientId { get; set; }
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

**User.cs**

```
[Table(nameof(User))]
public class User
{
    public virtual ICollection<User> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

**Client.cs**

```
[Table(nameof(Client))]
public class Client
{
    public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TimeRecord> TimeRecords { get; set; }
}
```

In My CustomDbContext in the OnModelCreating-Method I have added this to set the Default Behavior:

```
foreach (var relationship in builder.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(e => e.GetForeignKeys()))
{
    foreach (var foreignKeyProperty in relationship.Properties)
    {
        if (foreignKeyProperty != null && foreignKeyProperty.IsNullable)
        {
            relationship.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DeleteBehavior.Restrict set on: " + foreignKeyProperty.Name);
            relationship.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
        }
    }
}
```

Now after generating my migration I end up with:

```
table.ForeignKey(
    name: "FK_Project_User_OwnerId",
    column: x => x.OwnerId,
    principalTable: "User",
    principalColumn: "Id",
    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
```

and:

```
table.ForeignKey(
    name: "FK_Project_Client_ClientId",
    column: x => x.ClientId,
    principalTable: "Client",
    principalColumn: "Id",
    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
```

Why is it setting the onDelete for Client to ReferentialAction.Restrict and the onDelete for Owner to ReferentialAction.Cascade?!
Also is this a good way of setting the default behavior or is it rather critical and you would suggest just using the Fluent API to specify each relationship individually?

Comment: Your `ForeignKey` attributes are placed wrong. They should annotate the navigation properties, not the foreign keys themselves. It should be `[ForeignKey(nameof(Owner))]
    public virtual User Owner { get; set; }`

Comment: @Eldar AFAIK `ForeignKeyAttribute` can be placed on both key and relation and both approaches are valid. And if it would be placed on the relationship it should contain the key name `[ForeignKey(nameof(OwnerId))]public virtual User Owner { get; set; }`

Comment: Also in this particular case EF should be able to figure the relationship based on the convention so the attributes actually are not needed.

Comment: @Eldar I tried your suggestion anyway but the problem persists.

Comment: @GuruStron thanks for clearing that up. I prefer to specify the relationship that way. To me it is just much more readable

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was the ICollection Projects on User. Because each Entity in the DB-Scheme also has a reference to User f.e. CreationUserId, LastModifierUserId and DeleterUserId. Therefore I think EF could not assign the ICollection and resolve the Relationship properly. Removing the ICollection solved the issue and the DeleteBehavior got set to Restrict as expected. However, if I would need the ICollection I would have to specify the  relationship via Fluent API.